# What is a more appropriate API endpoint in my case?

Tags: java, spring

There are two controllers, "MediaController" and "UserController" in my spring project.

MediaController - contains CRUD endpoint related media

UserController - contains CURD endpoint related user

I want to make an endpoint which can retrieve "my" medias

Could you help me understand which option is better?

1. "/users/me/medias" - in UserController
2. "/medias/me" - in MediaController

or Is there a more standard option?

Looking forward to your insights.

Comment: While I get the close vote (especially because of OP's point 3...), this isn't really opinion based. We can answer this based on good design choices.

Answer (score 3):

Each controller manages one entity type. So if you're retrieving media, the endpoint should be in the MediaController.

Instead of making a new endpoint `media/me`, consider making `me` a filter on the normal GET (list) endpoint. That's much more scalable than having a new endpoint per thing you want to filter on. Let's say the next feature you want to add is filtering on media type. If you have both of those as filters on the same endpoint, now your users can combine those filters for free!

Answer (score 0):

When I structure my REST resources, I always start with the client view: What would be most helpful to a web programmer?

In your example I can imagine that you have a list of users, select one and display his media. Then your REST path should be `/users/{userId}/medias`. If you have lots of other resources that belong to a user, your web programmer still has to use just one endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To make the API experience more enjoyable for the average consumer, consider packaging condition sets within an easily accessible REST path. For example, the "my media" query can be packaged as GET /media/me.